# How do you simultaneously use `group_by()` and `ggplot_build()` with facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# Create the Data Frame
library(tidyverse)
library(ggQC)
set.seed(5555)
Golden_Egg_df <- data.frame(month = 1:12, 
                            egg_diameter = rnorm(n=12, mean=1.5, sd=0.2)) %>% 
  mutate(grp = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 9)))
Golden_Egg_df$egg_diameter[3] <- 5

# Determine the control limit values (red lines)
p <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  stat_QC(method = "XmR")
pb <- ggplot_build(p)
thres <- range(pb$data[[3]]$yintercept)

# Circle anything outside the control limits (red lines)
p + geom_point(
  data = subset(Golden_Egg_df,
                egg_diameter > max(thres) | egg_diameter < min(thres)),
  shape = 21,
  size = 4,
  col = "red"
)
```

[image: circled outlier]

The code chunk above determines the y-values of the control limits (red lines) from the `ggplot_build()` function. It then draws red circles around outliers. This works great until I facet the plot. It's because the logic of `thres <- range(pb$data[[3]]$yintercept)` isn't "smart" enough to wade through the different facet groupings.

```
# ONLY ONE 'Y-INTERCEPT' RANGE HERE TO WORRY ABOUT WITHOUT FACETING
#> $`data`[[3]]
#>   yintercept          y    x label
#> 1 -0.2688471 -0.2688471 -Inf   LCL
#> 2  3.7995203  3.7995203 -Inf   UCL
#> 3 -0.2688471 -0.2688471  Inf  -0.3
#> 4  3.7995203  3.7995203  Inf   3.8

# MULTIPLE 'Y-INTERCEPT' RANGES HERE TO WORRY ABOUT WITH FACETING
#> $`data`[[3]]
#>   yintercept          y    x label
#> 1 -0.8759612 -0.8759612 -Inf   LCL
#> 2  4.5303358  4.5303358 -Inf   UCL
#> 3 -0.8759612 -0.8759612  Inf  -0.9
#> 4  4.5303358  4.5303358  Inf   4.5
#> 5  1.2074161  1.2074161 -Inf   LCL
#> 6  1.9521532  1.9521532 -Inf   UCL
#> 7  1.2074161  1.2074161  Inf   1.2
#> 8  1.9521532  1.9521532  Inf     2
```

How do I get my code block below to work properly and circle the outliers? I obviously need a more sophisticated `thres2`, that can recognize there are different groupings of control limits (red lines) between the different facets.

```
# Determine the control limit values (red lines)
Golden_Egg_df$egg_diameter[11] <- 5
p2 <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  stat_QC(method = "XmR") + 
  facet_grid(~ grp, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = month.abb)
pb2 <- ggplot_build(p2)
thres2 <- range(pb2$data[[3]]$yintercept)
thres2
#> [1] -2.274056  7.445141

# Circle anything outside the control limits (red lines)
p2 + geom_point(
  data = subset(Golden_Egg_df,
                egg_diameter > max(thres2) | egg_diameter < min(thres2)),
  shape = 21,
  size = 4,
  col = "red"
)
```

[image: outlier faceted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to get the ranges in the same data.frame as your data. I'am not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but it works with your example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggQC)
set.seed(5555)
Golden_Egg_df <- data.frame(month = 1:12, 
                            egg_diameter = rnorm(n=12, mean=1.5, sd=0.2)) %>% 
  mutate(grp = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 9)))
Golden_Egg_df$egg_diameter[3] <- 5
Golden_Egg_df$egg_diameter[11] <- 5

# create the plot
p2 <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month,
                                y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  stat_QC(method = "XmR") + 
  facet_grid(~ grp,
             scales = "free_x",
             space = "free_x") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12,
                     labels = month.abb)

# get all the info about the plot
pb2 <- ggplot_build(p2)
# extract the UCL and LCL for each plot (facet)
Golden_Egg_df <- Golden_Egg_df %>% 
  mutate(min = ifelse(grp == "A", 
                      min(pb2$data[[3]]$yintercept[1:4]),    # LCL of 1st plot 
                      min(pb2$data[[3]]$yintercept[5:8])),   # LCL of 1st plot
         max = ifelse(grp == "A", 
                      max(pb2$data[[3]]$yintercept[1:4]),    # UCL 2nd plot 
                      max(pb2$data[[3]]$yintercept[5:8])))   # UCL 2nd plot

# add the circled outlier
p2 + geom_point(data = subset(Golden_Egg_df,
                              egg_diameter > max |
                                egg_diameter < min),
                shape = 21,
                size = 4,
                col = "red")
```

Cheers, Rico